# sqlplus pointing to libclntsh.so.21.1 which does not exists in $ORACLE_HOME/lib

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

When i run sqlplus command i am getting below error

`sqlplus: error while loading shared libraries: libclntsh.so.21.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I checked in the $ORACLE_HOME/lib directory and there is not file like `libclntsh.so.21.1`. However there is a file `libclntsh.so.19.1` in that directory.

Why is sqlplus pointing to 21.1 instead of 19.1. Where is this configured ?

Comment: It sounds like you have both versions installed and your environment isn't set up properly for either of them - i.e. `$PATH` includes the 21.1 `bin` and `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` includes the 19.1 `lib`. (Or they both but in different orders). Run `. oraenv` and see if that cleans things up?